# Currupted image saving android

Tags: android

1. when I'm click on popup that open camera. if i capture photo that save fine.
2. but if i go just in camera & exit without tacking photo than image save like given picture.

[image: Corrupted images].

3. if add any new image then all corrupted image replace by new like second image

[image: After add new image add to gallery or take from camera].

This is for taking picture

```
   builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals(getString(R.string.label_popup_takephoto))) //take photo
                {
                    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    Uri mPhotoUri;
                    if(bal.hasStorage(true))
                        mPhotoUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
                    else
                        mPhotoUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

                    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);

                    startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, 1);
                }
```

This is for stored image

```
    if (resultCode == -1) {// Camera
        Bitmap addphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.user);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Cursor cursor;
            String imagePath = null;
            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do 
                {
                    imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA));
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage=processimage(imagePath);
            //Bitmap yourSelectedImage = getScaledBitmap(imagePath, 500, 500);
            if (yourSelectedImage != null) {
                if (imgprofile != null) {
                    imgprofile.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                    picimagepath=imagePath;
                    bmp=yourSelectedImage;
                }
                else{
                    imgprofile.setImageBitmap(addphoto);
                }
            }
```

Hase Storage

```
public boolean hasStorage(boolean requireWriteAccess) 
{  
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();  

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {  
        return true;  
    } else if (!requireWriteAccess  
            && Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {  
        return true;  
    }  
    return false;  
}
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Simply check result code is cancel and request code is 1 in onActivityResult then delete file from given uri location :

```
if(resultCode ==RESULT_CANCELED){
   if(requestCode== 1) {
      File file = new File(getAbsolutePath(mPhotoUri));
      if (file.exists()) {
          file.delete();
      }
   }
}

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
      String id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[1];
      final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
      final String imageOrderBy = null;
      Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, imageColumns,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "="+id, null, imageOrderBy);
      if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
           return imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
      }else{
           return null;
      }
   }else{
      String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
      if (cursor != null) {
          int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          return cursor.getString(column_index);
      } else
          return null;
   }
 }
```

**Example :**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == -1) {// Camera
       Bitmap addphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.user);
       if (requestCode == 1) {
            Cursor cursor;
            String imagePath = null;
            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,new String[]{Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = processimage(imagePath);
            //Bitmap yourSelectedImage = getScaledBitmap(imagePath, 500, 500);
            if (yourSelectedImage != null) {
                if (imgprofile != null) {
                    imgprofile.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                    picimagepath = imagePath;
                    bmp = yourSelectedImage;
                 } else {
                    imgprofile.setImageBitmap(addphoto);
                 }
             }
        }
    }else if(resultCode == 0){
       if(requestCode == 1){
          File file = new File(getAbsolutePath(mPhotoUri));
          if (file.exists()) {
              file.delete();
          }
        }
     }else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
 }
```

Comment: it means i just put this  File file = new File(mPhotoUri);
      if (file.exists()) {
          file.delete();
      } in my code .. I have already declared (if(resultCode == -1) {// Camera) for result cancelled

Comment: RESULT_OK constant value is -1 and RESULT_CANCELED constant value is 0.

Comment: Sorry bro.. but im fresh in android... as per ur code i changed -1 to 0 in result code & file content code will put in my code in below cursor closed??   plz zgive me idea

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but i have question about (mPhotoUri) im using Uri mPhotoUri & it give error for change it to String .. then i replace it with (imagePath) it give RuntimeException error.

Comment: if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)   i'm using min sdk 9.

Comment: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is higher os version device not for min sdk.

Comment: in api 19 work. but when i cancel camera it give frailer  delivering result resultinfo arrayindexedoutofbound index-1, length-1

Comment: & what for the min sdk i have given support from 9 level.

Comment: look bro what happened in api level 9 & 10 work regular as it is, in api level 11 , 12 , 13 camera cant able to open , and in api level 14 to 18 it work same as with corrupted image & above 19 level it work for corrupt Image but as i said it throw arrayindexedoutofbound